# no known conversion for argument from ‘std::exponential_distribution<double> (*)(double)’ to ‘std::exponential_distribution<double>*'

Tags: c++, c++11, random, standard-library, std

I don't quite understand this error `g++` is throwing at me.

What is the difference between `std::exponential_distribution<double> (*)(double)` and `std::exponential_distribution<double>*` ?

The second is clearly a pointer to a `std::exponential_distribution` with template argument `<double>`, but what is the first?

Here is the code which causes the problem:

Firstly the function prototype

```
simulation(std::mt19937_64 *mt19937_64_pointer,
           std::uniform_real_distribution<double> *uniform_real_dis_p,
           std::exponential_distribution<double> *exp_dis_p)
{
    ...
}
```

And the code which calls this function:

```
std::mt19937_64 *gen_p = nullptr; // <-- this used to be: *&gen_p - hence the problem
    // Actually it isn't equal to nullptr - this is set elsewhere in the code

std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform_real_dis(0.0, 1.0);
std::exponential_distribution<double> exp_dis(1.0);

simulation s(gen_p, &uniform_real_dis, &exp_dis);
```

This is a bit of a strange error - I'm sure I could fix it if I understood fully what it meant. It does seem strange to me that the uniform distribution works and the exponential doesn't?

Comment: shouldn't it be `std::mt19937_64 *gen_p`? [this compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DG17fzRlmKLjoOpF)

Comment: That's strange why does that compile and mine does not.

Comment: I removed the `&`, are you sure you want both `*` and `&`?

Comment: Oh yes - that's probably it

Comment: Yeah it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your answer from the comments, but just for the record, `std::exponential_distribution<double> (*)(double)` is a function pointer type: a function taking one `double` and returning a `std::exponential_distribution<double>`.